# Render Multiple Charts in a Page with Canvas JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create multiple charts on a page with CanvasJS but facing problem to show this page getting error like CanvasJS is not defined in the console. How can I solve this problem? Furthermore, Is it possible to customize the piechart division colour?

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1",
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Spline Area Chart"
        },
        axisX: {
            interval: 10,
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "splineArea",
            color: "rgba(255,12,32,.3)",
            dataPoints: [
                { x: new Date(1992, 0), y: 2506000 },
                { x: new Date(1993, 0), y: 2798000 },
                { x: new Date(1994, 0), y: 3386000 },
                { x: new Date(1995, 0), y: 6944000 },
                { x: new Date(1996, 0), y: 6026000 },
                { x: new Date(1997, 0), y: 2394000 },
                { x: new Date(1998, 0), y: 1872000 },
                { x: new Date(1999, 0), y: 2140000 },
                { x: new Date(2000, 0), y: 7289000 },
                { x: new Date(2001, 0), y: 4830000 },
                { x: new Date(2002, 0), y: 2009000 },
                { x: new Date(2003, 0), y: 2840000 },
                { x: new Date(2004, 0), y: 2396000 },
                { x: new Date(2005, 0), y: 1613000 },
                { x: new Date(2006, 0), y: 2821000 }
            ]
        },
        ]
    });
chart.render();

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2",
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Pie Chart",
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "pie",
            showInLegend: true,
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 4181563, legendText: "PS 3", indexLabel: "PlayStation 3" },
                { y: 2175498, legendText: "Wii", indexLabel: "Wii" },
                { y: 3125844, legendText: "360", indexLabel: "Xbox 360" },
                { y: 1176121, legendText: "DS", indexLabel: "Nintendo DS" },
                { y: 1727161, legendText: "PSP", indexLabel: "PSP" },
                { y: 4303364, legendText: "3DS", indexLabel: "Nintendo 3DS" },
                { y: 1717786, legendText: "Vita", indexLabel: "PS Vita" }
            ]
        },
        ]
    });
chart.render();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<div id="chartContainer1" style="width: 45%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;"></div> 
<div id="chartContainer2" style="width: 45%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;"></div>
```

Comment: How do you add your script to the page? Setup of imports: 1. canvasjs 2. script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding CanvasJS script (canvasjs.min.js) should resolve the issue you are facing.

```
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

When it comes to changing the color of slices of pie chart, you can set [color in dataPoint level](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/color/) or have a [custom colorSet](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/colorset/). Below is an example with colorSet.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  CanvasJS.addColorSet("customColorSet1", [//colorSet Array

    "#47acb1",
    "#f26522",
    "#f9aa7b",
    "#a5a8aa",
    "#676766",
    "#add5d7",
    "#ffe8af",
    "#ffcd34" 
  ]);

  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    colorSet: "customColorSet1",
    title:{
      text: "Custom Color Set"
    },
    data: [{        
      type: "pie",
      dataPoints: [
        { y: 71 },
        { y: 55 },
        { y: 50 },
        { y: 65 },
        { y: 95 },
        { y: 68 },
        { y: 28 },
        { y: 34 },
        { y: 14 }
      ]
    }]
  });

  chart.render();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 270px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

PS: I would suggest you to have different variables for different chart instances like chart1, chart2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it this way.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", 

    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Spline Area Chart"
        },
        axisX: {
            interval: 10,
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "splineArea",
            color: "rgba(255,12,32,.3)",
            dataPoints: [
                { x: new Date(1992, 0), y: 2506000 },
                { x: new Date(1993, 0), y: 2798000 },
                { x: new Date(1994, 0), y: 3386000 },
                { x: new Date(1995, 0), y: 6944000 },
                { x: new Date(1996, 0), y: 6026000 },
                { x: new Date(1997, 0), y: 2394000 },
                { x: new Date(1998, 0), y: 1872000 },
                { x: new Date(1999, 0), y: 2140000 },
                { x: new Date(2000, 0), y: 7289000 },
                { x: new Date(2001, 0), y: 4830000 },
                { x: new Date(2002, 0), y: 2009000 },
                { x: new Date(2003, 0), y: 2840000 },
                { x: new Date(2004, 0), y: 2396000 },
                { x: new Date(2005, 0), y: 1613000 },
                { x: new Date(2006, 0), y: 2821000 }
            ]
        },
        ]
    });
chart.render();

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2",
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Pie Chart",
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "pie",
            showInLegend: true,
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 4181563, legendText: "PS 3", indexLabel: "PlayStation 3" },
                { y: 2175498, legendText: "Wii", indexLabel: "Wii" },
                { y: 3125844, legendText: "360", indexLabel: "Xbox 360" },
                { y: 1176121, legendText: "DS", indexLabel: "Nintendo DS" },
                { y: 1727161, legendText: "PSP", indexLabel: "PSP" },
                { y: 4303364, legendText: "3DS", indexLabel: "Nintendo 3DS" },
                { y: 1717786, legendText: "Vita", indexLabel: "PS Vita" }
            ]
        },
        ]
    });
chart.render();

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer3",
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Line Chart"
        },
        axisX: {
            valueFormatString: "MMM",
            interval: 1,
            intervalType: "month"
        },
        axisY: {
            includeZero: false
        },
        data: [
        {
          type: "line",
          dataPoints: [
              { x: new Date(2012, 00, 1), y: 450 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 01, 1), y: 414 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 02, 1), y: 520, indexLabel: "highest", markerColor: "red", markerType: "triangle" },
              { x: new Date(2012, 03, 1), y: 460 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 04, 1), y: 450 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 05, 1), y: 500 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 06, 1), y: 480 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 07, 1), y: 480 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 08, 1), y: 410, indexLabel: "lowest", markerColor: "DarkSlateGrey", markerType: "cross" },
              { x: new Date(2012, 09, 1), y: 500 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 10, 1), y: 480 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 11, 1), y: 510 }
            ]
        }
        ]
    });
chart.render();

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer4",
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Column Chart"
        },
        axisX: {
            interval: 10,
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "column",
            legendMarkerType: "triangle",
            legendMarkerColor: "green",
            color: "rgba(255,12,32,.3)",
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "Country wise population",
            dataPoints: [
                { x: 10, y: 297571, label: "India" },
                { x: 20, y: 267017, label: "Saudi" },
                { x: 30, y: 175200, label: "Canada" },
                { x: 40, y: 154580, label: "Iran" },
                { x: 50, y: 116000, label: "Russia" },
                { x: 60, y: 97800, label: "UAE" },
                { x: 70, y: 20682, label: "US" },
                { x: 80, y: 20350, label: "China" }
            ]
        },
        ]
    });
chart.render();
```

```html
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>  
<body>
<div id="chartContainer1" style="width: 45%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;"></div> 
<div id="chartContainer2" style="width: 45%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;"></div><br/>
<div id="chartContainer3" style="width: 45%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;"></div>
<div id="chartContainer4" style="width: 45%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;"></div>
</body>
```